# superClass's field is null

Tags: java, cglib

i'm new bee about cglib , today i write some code by `cglib` , code show as below

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //filed
        UserService userService = new UserService();

        RealSubject realSubject = new RealSubject();
        realSubject.setUserService(userService);
        Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();

        enhancer.setSuperclass(realSubject.getClass());

        enhancer.setCallback((MethodInterceptor) (obj, method, args1, proxy) 
                      -> proxy.invokeSuper(obj, args1));
        realSubject = (RealSubject) enhancer.create();
        realSubject.doService();

         // i expect get userService but null 
        System.out.println(realSubject.getUserService());
    }
}
```

os : `uname -a`

`txt
Darwin tes.local 17.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

jdk : `java -version`

`➜  ~ java -version
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)`

how can i get the field? , Please forgive my bad english.

Comment: what field are you talking about? Your code doesn't show any fields, only local variables

Comment: @Stultuske I think he is referring to userService

Comment: @Stultuske i'm referring ro userService, i found `Enhancer` can't holder the instance object  like realSubject，do you have any good advice？

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you are talking about :/ Is this code you wrote yourself? You mean you want to pass userService to your Enhancer class? What does the toString from UserService return?

Comment: Either way, what you are printing there, is not the result of "realSubject.getUserService()", but the result of "realSubject.getUserService().toString()"

Comment: @Stultuske I may not express it clearly. but Whether it is toString() or an instance, the data will always be printed, it will not be null. now it is null,if i direct use userService , will throw NPE

Comment: seeing as you don't show any of the relevant code, all we can do is keep on guessing.

Comment: thanks for your patience  , liks a pojo , just a field userService

Comment: <code>`  public class RealSubject implements ISubjectService {

    private UserService userService;  
    @Override
    public void doService() {
        System.out.println("doService ing。。。。");
    }
    public UserService getUserService() {
        return userService;
    }
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
}                    `</code>

Comment: and what does this: realSubject = (RealSubject) enhancer.create(); do?

Comment: emmm, create a proxy by cglib , i think is right。

Comment: yes, no doublt, but, my point is: you first set an instance of RealSubject to realSubject. In this instance, you set an instance of UserService. but afterwards, you call a .create method, without knowing what it does, and cast that to a RealSubject, and overwrite your first realSubject with this. so maybe that create maps your objects wrong and nullifies your service

Comment: yeah ， this is my key question and doublt , put a .class to Enhancer can't holder current instance , so we can't get the field ,  so i update the cglib source code for get userService , but if i don't change source code ,  is there any  other way?, anyway ， thinks for your reply , please forgive me bad english.